# Systemd service for fetching data from the web at startup

Tags: permissions, systemd, systemd-networkd

I would like to fetch a random picture from unsplash in `/usr/share/wallpapers` each time I reboot my laptop.

I wrote this service as a first try:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fetch random picture from unsplash
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/nicolas/.local/bin/fetch_unsplash_1920x1080

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

I enabled it, reboot and I see it fails because:

```
déc. 19 13:21:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Fetch random picture from unsplash.
déc. 19 13:21:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1728]: fetch_unsplash.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
déc. 19 13:21:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1728]: fetch_unsplash.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/nicolas/.local/bin/fetch_unsplash_1920x1080: Permission denied
déc. 19 13:21:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: fetch_unsplash.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
déc. 19 13:21:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: fetch_unsplash.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
```

The path for the script is correct and the script has execution permission.

Here is code (it's also a base for future improvements):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

location="$1"
if [ -z "$location" ]
then
    location="/usr/share/wallpapers"
fi
name="random_unsplash_1920x1080.jpg"
wget -q "https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random" --output-document "$location/$name"
```

So what does not work?

Also this raises two problems for me: how to give permission to the service for writing in `/usr/share/wallpapers`? And how to get the service start only when the laptop is truly connected to internet (am I doing it right in this service)?

Comment: Can you show the permissions for that script, because systemd disagrees with you: `Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/nicolas/.local/bin/fetch_unsplash_1920x1080: Permission denied`.  Also, is your /home filesystem mounted with the `noexec` flag?  Check the filesystem  you're on with `df /home/nicolas/.local/bin/fetch_unsplash_1920x1080` followed by `mount | grep ... that filesystem`

Comment: The script has the permission `-rwxr-xr-x`, the filesystem  where the script is located is not mounted with `noexec`. Also the location where the script is trying to write is not on the same partition and it has the same mount options.

Comment: My only other thought was that (if /home is indeed a separate filesystem), that it's not mounted when this unit tries to execute; seems rather unlikely, given the `After=network-online.target`, but thought I'd mention it, just in case.